# How to configure Work Manager to annotation based MDB

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic server 12C and I am using MDB with annotation based and trying to add the Workmanager with max constraint of 1000 where I am not able to map the work manager name to war file and I have only weblogic.xml and no weblogic-ejb-jar.xml. Please suggest how to map workmanager to the application.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without XML. Why can't you use a `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`?

Comment: It is working with weblogic-ejb-jar.xml do we have any annotation stuff.

Comment: No you do not have those kind of annotation in the EJB 3 spec as it is weblogic specific.